# SOAP Request error... why am I getting a NRE?

Tags: .net, asp.net, xml, vb.net, soap

I pretty much copy and pasted the code from the API PDF, but am getting a Null reference Exception on line:

```
AccountArray(0) = AccountToUpdate
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

```
Dim boolQueryFinished = False
Dim strCurrentID As String = "0"
Dim contractid As Integer
Dim strWebURI As String = "https://webservices.autotask.net/atservices/1.5/atws.asmx"
Dim myService As New ATWS
myService.Url = strWebURI
Dim cred As New System.Net.NetworkCredential("U", "P")
Dim credCache As New System.Net.CredentialCache
credCache.Add(New Uri(myService.Url), "Basic", cred)
myService.Credentials = credCache
Dim AccountID As New ArrayList
Dim i As Integer
While Not (boolQueryFinished)
Dim strQuery As String = "<queryxml><entity>Contract</entity>" & _
"<query><condition><field>id<expression op=""greaterthan"">" & strCurrentID &
"</expression></field></condition></query>" & _
"</queryxml>"
Dim r As ATWSResponse
r = myService.query(strQuery)
If r.EntityResults.Length > 0 Then
    For Each ent As Entity In r.EntityResults 
        strCurrentID = ent.id
        AccountID.Add(CType(ent, Contract).AccountID)

    Next
Else
    boolQueryFinished = True
    While i < ContractName.Count
        listOutput.Items.Add(ContractName(i))
        listOutput.Items.Add(id(i))
        If ContractName(i).Contains("Georges") Then
            listOutput.Items.Add("Found it")
            Dim sResponse As ATWSResponse
            Dim AccountToUpdate As New Contract
            Dim AccountArray(0) As Contract
            AccountToUpdate.AccountID = AccountID(i)


            AccountArray(0) = AccountToUpdate
            Dim entityArray() As Entity = CType(AccountArray, Entity())
            sResponse = myService.update(entityArray)

            If sResponse.ReturnCode = 1 Then
                listOutput.Items.Add("Updated")
            Else
                listOutput.Items.Add("Failed")

            End If
        End If

        i = i + 1
    End While
    listOutput.Items.Add(id.Count)
    listOutput.Items.Add(ContractName.Count)
End If
End While
```

Comment: You'll need to post the entire `else` block, up until the `End While`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that:

- The `r.EntityResults.Length` is not greater than zero. You've fallen into the `else` clause.
- The `While i < ContractName.Count` loop was entered (it's not clear what this `ContractName` is, though.
- `i` isn't initialized yet, so it's value is `0`.
- From what we can see posted above, we should have seen an `ArgumentOutOfRange Exception`, as we're trying to get to index 0 of an empty ArrayList.

AccountToUpdate.AccountID = AccountID(i)

Are you sure you meant to have the `While` loop within the `Else` block? I'm curious where the `End If` statement is?

Comment: I added the rest of it. 1. r.EntityResults.Length is above 0 if the query is succesful and keeps running and adds the values into arrays: AccountID.Add(CType(ent, Contract).AccountID). Once it hits 0 it stops and the Else kicks in and puts together a response and tries to send it back.

Comment: ContractName is an array also that gets added info to it in the r.EntityResults.Length IF

Comment: Ugh I was spelling a variable name worng. Got it Thanks!